# C language: How would I write a function to print one row per line?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm brand new to programming in C with arrays, and I'm wondering if you could give me some pointers on how to write an NxN matrix with all values initialized to 1, and then print the matrix one row per line.

MATLAB is the only language in which I know of an easy solution. Any tips for doing this in C? Thank you!!

Alec

Comment: Please show your efforts, preferably code.

Comment: Just print each element in the row without breaking line, and then only use the `\n` when entering the next row.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this..

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
 for(j = 0; j < N ; j++){
  printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}
```

You started learning C now. No issues we are ready to help you. :)